# JQuery Mobile 1.3.2 delay on checkbox toggle

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.2 and found that there is delay when I toggle checkbox within checked / unchecked.

If I add "$.mobile.buttonmarkup.hoverdelay = 0" to mobileinit and it works well but the checkbox get checked when scrolling.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: How do you toggle it?

Comment: By toggle - I mean check and uncheck the checkbox

Comment: I mean, you check/uncheck it dynamically? Or manually?

Comment: Trying to check/uncheck it manually.